# Make javascript run onclick instead of pageload

Tags: javascript

I have the the following script that runs when the page is loaded:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
     j=parseInt(Math.random()*ranobjList.length);
     j=(isNaN(j))?0:j;
     document.write(unescape(ranobjList[j]));
</script>
```

How can I execute it when a button is clicked rather then when it loads?

Comment: You could wrap that code inside a function and bind it to the button. Google it, it's easy.

Answer (score 2):

put it in a function, and call it on an onclick event on an element

```
function myEvent() {
    j=parseInt(Math.random()*ranobjList.length);
    j=(isNaN(j))?0:j;
    document.write(unescape(ranobjList[j]));
}
```

then in your html

```
<input type='button' value='Click Me' onclick='myEvent();' />
```

Answer (score 0):

The code example you have isn't actually running on page load. It's running as it's interpreted by the DOM.

But here is a solution to your request.

The HTML button must be above the script tag. So you'll want something just like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me for action" id="actionButton" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("actionButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        j=parseInt(Math.random()*ranobjList.length);
        j=(isNaN(j))?0:j;
        document.write(unescape(ranobjList[j]));
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Ben. So do I have to label the input button to have that script detect it?  I have a bunch of other buttons in the page that are linked to other scripts.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see you wanted it attached to a button. I've edited my code so it should fit what you're requesting.

Comment: oh sorry.  didnt see your changes! thanks I'll try that

Comment: doesnt seem to work.  I just get a blank page. probably should have said at the start, this is a jquery mobile page...is there a better jquery solution?